# How To Append An Extra Element?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add an extra element to a preexisting `.append`. I found a ton of threads on the subject, but none of them appeared to have similar enough code for me to feed off of.

---

**My Original Code:**

```
$this.children('.sdm_placeholder').append('<a href="'+value['permalink']+'"><span class="sdm_post_title" style="cursor:pointer;">'+value['title']+'</span></a>');
```

I took the original code and added `<span class="sdm_post_date">'+value['date']+'</span>` to the end, but nothing popped up on the front-end. I believe I have "date" defined correctly in my PHP, so I'm assuming I messed up on the append.

---

**With My Addition:**

```
$this.children('.sdm_placeholder').append('<a href="'+value['permalink']+'"><span class="sdm_post_title" style="cursor:pointer;">'+value['title']+'</span></a><span class="sdm_post_date">'+value['date']+'</span>');
```

In the case my PHP is wrong, wouldn't the span still show up in the DOM, but just without a value?

Comment: Is there any errors on the console?

Comment: No, no errors at the moment

Comment: Have you inspect the page at the position where should be printed to see if there is not nothing at all?

Comment: You say you have defined `date` in PHP.. but you need it in Javascript. If you have the variable in PHP you need to use `<?php echo $date; ?>`.

Comment: @Gonzalo - Yes, nothing shows up in my dev tools.

Comment: @BasvanStein - This is someone else's code that I'm trying to build off of. They designed it to have the JS file populate the page and not the PHP, so I would prefer to keep it consistent.

Comment: @CSSApprentice Instead of `'+value['date']+'` try some hard coded value to see if that appears. For eg: `<span class="sdm_post_date">this should appear</span>`

Comment: @BasvanStein - Let me expand, my answer could have been more thorough. This is how they call the Title, Link, and Image. Maybe those are better to call in the JS, but not the date?

Comment: @CSSApprentice my point was that if you have the date as PHP variable, you can not just use it in Javascript... as you try.

Comment: @Yahya - Good thinking! It did not show up

Comment: @CSSApprentice and the other anchor/span are appearing as normal?

Comment: @Yahya - I see it in the js file in the Sources tab, so I know my DOM read it. Is the way I appended the second item correct?

Comment: @Yahya - Yes, the anchor was unaffected by the change, and spans appear as they normally would.

Comment: @CSSApprentice By the looks of it, it should work, seems like you have other issues. Can you breakdown the appendee? Let's say, in first step append the first span and in another step the next one?

Comment: @Yahya - Yes, that would be fine! I'll do that now, but if you want to add it as an answer, I'll check it and accept it

Comment: @Yahya - Actually, I couldn't get that to work either. Tried a couple of different approaches, but it still doesn't show up

Comment: If anyone can help me solve this in the next hour, I will start a 100 point bounty when it's available and award them the points! I need to get this fixed asap :/

Comment: Can you try this: `$this.children('.sdm_placeholder').append("<a href="+value['permalink']+"><span class='sdm_post_title' style='cursor:pointer;'>"+value['title']+"</span></a><span class='sdm_post_date'>"+value['date']+"</span>");` ?